# NOT able to use Xlrd module in python

Tags: python, module, python-3.x, xlrd

Question: i M not able to use xlrd module though i have installed the same???

Error obtained :

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "D:\xlrd_1.py", line 1, in <module> 
    import xlrd 
  File "D:\Python31\lib\xlrd\__init__.py", line 345 
    u"Consolidate_Area": u"\x00", 
                      ^ 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Code :

```
import xlrd
print ("hi")
```

Some more description:

1. I m using python 3.1,
2. I have installed xlrd-0.7.1.win32.exe (md5) taken from
   http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd/0.7.1.
3. able to see the xlrd package in python\Lib\Site-packages
4. tried copying to include file also which didnt work.

Need help on this..searched stackoverflow for the same problem as well as else where i didnt find answer so posting the same

Appreciate for any help on the same

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python 3.
But the XLRD library you are using is written in Python 2!
(I wonder you succeeded in installing it)

Try to use the package [xlrd3](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd3/0.1.4) for Python 3